# C++-20 Modules and CMake 3.28 : Multiple "error: 'wxXXXXXX' has different definitions in different modules" errors

Tags: c++, cmake, module, clang, clang++

CMake 3.28 has been released with first class support for C++ 20 modules (using Clang >= 17 at least).
I'm getting several errors like this in the build output.

```
[ ... snip ... ]
[build] [10/12] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Modules.dir/Debug/src/modules/HSUtil.cpp.o
[build] FAILED: CMakeFiles/Modules.dir/Debug/src/modules/HSUtil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Modules.dir/Debug/HS.Util.pcm 
[build] /usr/bin/clang++ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXGTK__ -DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\" -I/home/geoffrey/dev/scratch/t/include -I/home/geoffrey/dev/scratch/t/modules -I/home/geoffrey/dev/scratch/t/src/include -I/home/geoffrey/dev/scratch/t/src/modules -I/usr/local/lib64/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.3 -isystem /home/geoffrey/dev/sys/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include -isystem /usr/local/lib64/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-static-3.3 -isystem /usr/local/include/wx-3.3 -pthread -g -std=c++20 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/Modules.dir/Debug/src/modules/HSUtil.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/Modules.dir/Debug/src/modules/HSUtil.cpp.o.d @CMakeFiles/Modules.dir/Debug/src/modules/HSUtil.cpp.o.modmap -o CMakeFiles/Modules.dir/Debug/src/modules/HSUtil.cpp.o -c /home/geoffrey/dev/scratch/t/src/modules/HSUtil.cpp
[build] In file included from /home/geoffrey/dev/scratch/t/src/modules/HSUtil.cpp:35:
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/wx-3.3/wx/wx.h:23:
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/wx-3.3/wx/event.h:29:
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/wx-3.3/wx/any.h:599:
[build] /usr/local/include/wx-3.3/wx/datetime.h:752:17: error: 'wxDateTime' has different definitions in different modules; first difference is defined here found method 'IsValid' with body
[build]   752 |     inline bool IsValid() const { return m_time != wxLongLong(wxINT64_MIN); }
[build]       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /usr/local/include/wx-3.3/wx/datetime.h:752:17: note: but in 'HS.Debug.<global>' found method 'IsValid' with different body
[build]   752 |     inline bool IsValid() const { return m_time != wxLongLong(wxINT64_MIN); }
[build]       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ ... snip ... ]
```

I've been stuck on this for about 5 days now. ChatGPT and Bing aren't any help. I've rebuilt everything with static linkage and with shared libraries, checked all the compile options are compatible, and everything else AI can think of without success.
Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_SCAN_FOR_MODULES)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES .a)

set(wxWidgets_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE /usr/local/bin/wx-config)

get_filename_component(PROJECT_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE} DIRECTORY)
get_filename_component(PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_ROOT} NAME)

# Executable names
set(APP ${PROJECT_NAME})

# Project name
project(${APP} LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.1.0)

include_directories(
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/modules"
    "${VCPKG_PATH}/include"
    "/usr/local/lib64/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.3"
)

# APP executable
add_executable(${APP}
    src/app.cpp
    src/frame.cpp
)
if(WIN32)
target_sources(${APP} PUBLIC
    ${APP}.rc)
endif(WIN32)

add_library(Modules)
target_sources(Modules PUBLIC FILE_SET CXX_MODULES FILES
    src/modules/HSDebug.cpp
    src/modules/HSUtil.cpp
)

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS core base)
include("${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}")
target_link_libraries(${APP} PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(Modules PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(${APP} PRIVATE Modules)
```

Any ideas, peeps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been stuck on this for about 5 days now.

These *are* hard to debug.

It looks like `wxINT64_MIN` can have different definitions in `include/wx/defs.h`:

```
#ifdef LLONG_MAX
    #define wxINT64_MIN LLONG_MIN
...
#else
    #define wxINT64_MIN (wxLL(-9223372036854775807)-1)
```

I suspect that when you compile the `HSUtil.cpp` you take one branch, but when you compiled some other module earlier you took the other branch.

You can add `#error This should not be used` to one branch (the one you think shouldn't be used) and compile everything *without* modules.

That build will probably fail due to the added `#error`.

Now move the `#error` to the other branch and try rebuilding everything again.

That will probably *also* fail, and now you have identified two sources which are using different definitions.

The `#define LLONG_MIN ...` is probably coming from `<limits.h>`, and one of your sources has `#include <limits.h>` before `#include <wx/defs.h>`, while the other source doesn't.

Comment: Genius! I get the error message in both paths, so it is choosing different paths for different files.

Comment: Phhhhhew. Found it. In one of my source files, 

#include <wx/wx.h>

was at the top, and in another, it was right at the bottom of the includes.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.